# PHP Multidimensional Array Search (WHERE clause)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

My PDO wrapper returns the following array when I pass in "SELECT * FROM setting":

```
Array( 
[0] => Array
    (
        [setting_id] => 1
        [setting_title] => application_title
        [setting_value] => My Website
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [setting_id] => 2
        [setting_title] => application_theme
        [setting_value] => default
    )      
)
```

I'd like some way to manipulate this array so I can use something like the following:

```
echo $this->setting['application_title']; // prints "My Website"
```

Similarly

```
echo $this->setting['application_theme']; // prints "default"
```

I'm basically looking for a WHERE clause in a multidimensional array. Any help is appreciated, I'm probably missing something stupid.

**EDIT**

I've managed to find a solution by using a foreach loop. I created a function which prepares the settings array, which takes the array from the PDO wrapper as a parameter.

```
private function PrepareSettings($array) {
    foreach($array as $value => $key) {
        $this->settings[$key['setting_title']] = $key['setting_value'];
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else with the same problem. 
If anyone knows of a more efficient way I'd love to hear it!

**ANOTHER EDIT**

@hakre introduced me to a much better solution, using the array_column function. Here's his example using my extracts: http://3v4l.org/E8DE3

Comment: As far as I can see that's just how PDO returns the array. If I were able to make the array associative it would help, and probably fix the issue.

Comment: If the array you pasted above is what is returned from your select statement, surely you know it's the select statement that needs the where clause? Am I missing what you're missing?

Comment: Ah okay, now I understand what you mean. You're looking for http://php.net/array_column , make use of the key column, too, that's the `setting_title` in your case.

Comment: @Fo. I need to select all the settings as the code is an abstract from the bootstrap of my application which defines the global settings for the session. But thank you, anyway.

Comment: Example: http://3v4l.org/E8DE3

Comment: @hakre: That's brilliant! I'd never heard of the array_column function - exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you